# Common RegEx pattern to substitute multiple elements

Tags: regex, perl

In my Perl program, I am having following variables in an array that are to be eliminated:

```
$array[0] = "--_000_41DADE848657754488503BD616F1ADE607250A88abmail2k7adventure_--";
$array[1] = "--_000_41DADE848657754488503BD616F1ADE607317EE6abmail2k7adventure_";
$array[2] = "--_000_41DADE848657754488503BD616F1ADE6073C5F3Babmail2k7adventure_--";
```

For different input data, I get different elements which are similar to that. How do I eliminate them by having a single regex? I am a beginner at regex, I tried the following but it dint work as expected.

```
$array =~ s/--_000_ .* adventure_--//g;
```

Comment: You want to remove the elements from the array? `splice @array, 0, 2`. You want to overwrite them? `@array[0..2] = ()`. Sounds more like you want to remove *part* of the strings, in which case you'd need to tell us what you want to remove.

Comment: @diEcho: I want to replace them by a blank, just eliminate them.

Comment: @rad No, see that is two conflicting statements. You *either* want to replace the array elements with blanks, *or* you want to delete them.

Comment: @TLP: I would prefer to delete them. How do I do that?

Comment: Note that the location of these strings is not fixed, they could be anywhere in the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to remove a particular type of element from a list, you can use [`grep`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/grep.html):

```
my @new = grep !/^--_000_ .* adventure_--/, @array;
```

Comment: @rad Of course it works. The only difficulty was trying to understand what you wanted, but I think this is it.

Comment: Thanks. I was wondering if this is possible?
my @array = grep !/^--_000_ .* adventure_--/, @array;

Comment: @rad - It probably is. I think @array is listified as an argument to grep. Try `@ary = (1,2,3,4,5,6,7);@ary = grep !/[1357]/, @ary;for (@ary){print "'$_'\n"}` as a test.

Comment: @rad It is not possible to re-declare another copy of `@array` with `my @array`, but it is possible to assign the result of the `grep` back to `@array`.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want to remove all elements that match that pattern?

There's other shorthand ways to do this, but the simplest to understand would probably be to create a new array while emptying the old one, either with a loop:

```
my @newarray= ();
while ($elem = shift @array) {
    push @newarray, $elem if ($elem !~ /^--_000_ .* adventure_--/);
}
```

Or using grep:

```
my @newarray = grep !/^--_000_ .* adventure_--/, @array;
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, this might sound stupid. But the following pattern worked!

```
$array=~ s/--_000_.*adventure_//g;
```

I just removed the spaces surrounding .*